# substituir a imagem externa incorporada pelo usuário pela nova versão do host local

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Bom dia,

Estou utilizando um plugin chamado Image Teleporter, ele pega todas as imagens que o usuario vai enviar em anexo e salva automaticamente na biblioteca do wordpress.

Gostaria de saber como faço para subistituir a imagem que o usuario enviou em anexo, pela que está na biblioteca do wordpress.

O motivo disto é validar a imagem, visto que nem sempre o usuario vai enviar com uma url segura.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O plugin em questão está descontinuado, sendo assim não funciona mais.

Porém eu utilizo um outro plugin para fazer basicamente a mesma coisa.

https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/import-external-attachments/

Ele salva as imagens de posts e pages na bliblioteca de mídia do WordPress.